# Диапазоны дат на Python

Tags: python

Возникла необходимость написать скрипт на питоне с которым знаком очень поверхностно. Нужно написать скрипт который по введённой дате определяет её принадлежность к диапазону дат и выводит к какому диапазону она принадлежит.

**На пример:** Есть список церковных постов с датами и названиями, я ввожу дату и получаю к какому посту принадлежит дата или null если день не постный.

Comment: Укажите, где вы храните значения дат, с которыми нужно сравнивать.

Comment: Скорее всего в самом тексте программы в виде какой-либо структуры, здесь всё можно варировать. БД смысла подключать ни какого т.к диапазонов всего 8-10 границы и количество если и будут меняться то очень редко.

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Программу за тебя написать, что ли? StackOverflow он как бы для другого, бро, он для помощи по конкретным вопросам, когда человек посреди работы застрял из-за багули неведомой. А с такой постановкой тебе на фриланс лучше, студент за отзыв напишет.

Comment: @AntonMelnikov данный вопрос не слишком конкретный и поэтому может быть не слишком полезен для будущих посетителей сайта (хотя если человек, интересующийся работой с диапазонами дат в Питоне, выучит хотя бы что можно использовать *datetime* модуль и *сравнивать его объекты напрямую* из опубликованных ответов, то это уже плюс). Если вопрос полезен другим, то не имеет никакого значения способность автора найти решение самостоятельно. У вас ошибочное представление о целях существования сайта (простыня сломанного кода не является хорошим вопросом). См. [Работа за автора](https://goo.gl/1QsVN1)

Comment: @jfs По моему представлению, прежде чем просить помощи, человек должен попробовать сделать это сам. Открыть шикарнейший library reference, увидеть модуль datetime, прочитать о методах. Элементарно загуглить "python сравнить даты". Просмотрел обсуждение, на которое ссылаетесь. ИМХО, такая постановка задачи, как у автора - не повод для закрытия, флагов я ему не выставлял. Но задуматься о жизни надо, поэтому я просто комментарий оставил.

Comment: @AntonMelnikov я согласен с тем что вы говорите, но это не имеет отношения к тому какие вопросы должны быть на сайте ("для другого" или нет). Прочтите ссылку, которую я дал, подумайте (это сложный вопрос—я не верю что вы могли его так быстро освоить). Комментарии не место для мета-обсуждений. Если вы думаете вам есть что сказать, то опубликуйте свой ответ на Мете в существующей теме или новую откройте (как хотите).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime

class DATE(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        '''список церковных постов с датами и названиями'''
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            start, stop = v
            self[k] = datetime.date(*start), datetime.date(*stop)

    def compare(self, date_):
        '''по введённой дате определяет её принадлежность к диапазону дат'''
        d_ = datetime.date(*date_)
        for post_name in self:
            start, stop = self[post_name]
            if start <= d_ <= stop:  # определяет
                return post_name  # выводит к какому диапазону она принадлежит


# Есть список церковных постов с датами и названиями
d = DATE(
    post_1=[(2016, 1, 1), (2016, 1, 10)],
    post_2=[(2016, 3, 5), (2016, 4, 11)]
)


# я ввожу дату и получаю к какому посту принадлежит дата или null если день не постный
print(d.compare((2016, 1, 5)))
print(d.compare((2016, 3, 5)))
print(d.compare((2016, 12, 5)))
```

out:

```
post_1
post_2
None
```

Comment: Использование наследования здесь не оправдано. Нет необходимости новую коллекцию создавать, чтобы набор постов хранить. Поиск к какому посту относится дата, можно как функцию реализовать и даже если вы используете класс , то `DATE` не лучшее имя.

Answer (score 7):

Про работу с датами в Python на [русском](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html).

Но в данном конкретном случае проще использовать обычные логические операторы, например:

```
return (t1start <= t2 <= t1end)
```

вернет True в случае, если t2 находится в интервале между t1start и t1end.

В результате, если у нас список дат - это словарь, где ключ - индекс интервала (или название праздника), а значение - это кортеж с началом и концом интервала `{1:(t1start,t1end), 2:(t2start,t2end), ..., N:(tNstart,tNend)}`, то проверять можно следующей функцией:

```
def (check_date, intervals):
    for index, interval in intervals:
        t1start, t1end = interval
        if (t1start <= check_date <= t1end):
            return index
    return None
```

Данная функция вернет значение ключа словаря в случае, если *check_date* окажется в соответствующем интервале. В противном случае функция вернет *None*

Проверяемая дата и границы интервалов должны быть типа date

```
from datetime import date
```

Comment: Чтобы понять пересекаются ли заданные интервалы дат `a`,`b`, можно проще условие использовать: [`a.start <= b.end and b.start <= a.end`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3269434/4279)

Comment: Немного не верно в примере указал. Чтобы убедиться, что дата d1 находится в интервале между t_start и t_end, должно быть истинным условие `t_start <= d1 <= t_end`

Answer (score 5):

В стандартной библиотеке python есть модуль `datetime`, в котором есть средства для работы с датой и временем.

Простой пример:

```
import datetime
delta = datetime.date.today() - datetime.date(1987, 12, 28)  # разница текущим днем и моим днем рождения:) - объект timedelta
print(delta.days)  # Разница между датами в днях, на сегодня это 10521

# Пример разбора даты из текста:
sdate = "17.10.2016"
d =  datetime.datetime.strptime(sdate, '%d.%m.%Y')
print(d)  # Объект даты-времени: datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 17, 0, 0)
```

Для объектов `date` и `datetime` попадание в диапазон дат можно проверять просто с помощью операторов `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, в том числе и так: `d1 <= d <= d2`

[**Документация по модулю datetime**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 3):

> Есть список церковных постов с датами и названиями, я ввожу дату и получаю к какому посту принадлежит дата или null если день не постный.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
from collections import namedtuple

DateRange = namedtuple('DateRange', 'start end')
dates = {
    'Великий Пост': make_date_range("14 марта – 30 апреля 2016"),
    'Петров пост': make_date_range("27 июня – 11 июля 2016"),
    # ...
}    
now = datetime.now()
fast = next((name for name, r in dates.items() if r.start <= now < r.end), None)
```

`fast` это имя поста или `None`, если нет поста сегодня (не включая `.end` дату—используйте `<= r.end` чтобы включить конечную дату если необходимо), где:

```
import re

def make_date_range(date_range_string):
    d1, m1, d2, m2, year = re.match(r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)\s*–\s*(\d+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\d+)",
                                    date_range_string).groups()
    months = {'марта': 3, 'апреля': 4, 'июня': 6, 'июля': 7} # ...
    return DateRange(datetime(int(year), months[m1], int(d1)), 
                     datetime(int(year), months[m2], int(d2)))
```

Связанный вопрос: [find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8534256/4279)

---

Если есть список дат, то можно быстро найти к какому диапазону/интервалу дат относится введённая дата, используя [`bisect` модуль, который выполняет двоичный поиск по отсортированному списку](https://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import bisect

Y = datetime.now().year
seasons = [datetime(*args) for args in [
    (Y, 1, 1), # winter
    (Y, 3, 1), # spring
    (Y, 6, 1), # summer
    (Y, 9, 1), # autumn
    (Y, 12, 1) # winter
]]
season_names = [None, 'winter', 'spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter']

index = bisect(seasons, datetime.now())
print(season_names[index])
# -> autumn
```